# Prevent R plumber from wrapping errors to trigger Docker restart

Tags: r, docker, plumber

I have an API that is running inside a Docker container that has been started with the `--restart unless-stopped` flag. That is, if an error occurs inside the executed R script, the whole container will restart (which, in my case, would most probably solve the error in question).

However, as per the [official documentation](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/rendering-output.html#error-handling) on error handling,

> Plumber wraps each endpoint invocation so that it can gracefully capture errors. [...] This means that it is possible for you to intentionally stop() in an endpoint or a filter as a way to communicate a problem to your user.

So each error *inside* an API function / endpoint is captured and forwarded to the client as a `500 - Internal Server Error` response. This means that the error does not actually lead to the current process / execution (i.e. the API) being stopped, thus not triggering the desired restart of the Docker container.

Take this MWE:

```r
#* Echo back the input
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  
  if (msg == "Error"){
    stop("This does not stop the API!")
  }
  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

With the API running locally, `curl "http://localhost:8000/echo?msg=Error"` will return:

```
{"error":["500 - Internal server error"],"message":["Error in (function (msg = \"\") : This does not stop the API!\n"]}
```

... and the API will continue running. By contrast, if I put the same `stop()` command inside the `plumber.R` script, but *outside* any endpoint specification, the API will crash (or rather, won't start at all):

```r
print("Starting API")

if (TRUE){
  stop("This prevents the API from starting")
}

#* Echo back the input
#* @param msg The message to echo
#* @get /echo
function(msg="") {
  
  if (msg == "Error"){
    stop("This does not stop the API!")
  }

  list(msg = paste0("The message is: '", msg, "'"))
}
```

Hitting "Run API" in RStudio will yield:

```
> plumber::plumb(file='plumber.R')$run()
[1] "Starting API"
Error in stopOnLine(lineNum, file[lineNum], e) : 
  Error on line #4: '' - Error in eval(expr, envir): This prevents the API from starting
```

This is an actual error that would trigger the Docker restart.

Is there a way to prevent plumber from wrapping errors in the API and make the API crash instead (as in "regular" R code)? I'm fine with the general idea behind this approach and I see that it makes sense in most cases to forward the error to the user rather than having the whole API crash. But I'm looking for a way to "force-evaluate" the error as such in some specific cases. I have played around with [error handlers](https://www.rplumber.io/reference/pr_set_error.html) and the like, but to no avail so far.

NB: I have found a solution to my initial problem by now that does not require a restart of the Docker container -- however, I'm still curious whether one can circumvent the default plumber behavior of wrapping errors.